# How to post parameters from angular to rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, post

I am fairly new to angular and i am trying to send a name and image file to my server which is written in rails. But the data i am being received on my server is not correct and i have tried many fixes but nothing seems to be working. The request payload that being sent is this

```
-----WebKitFormBoundaryhRvQy5dRArcb6BfP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="project[logo]"; filename="badge.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryhRvQy5dRArcb6BfP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="project[name]"

abc
------WebKitFormBoundaryhRvQy5dRArcb6BfP--
```

This is not being accepted in rails server and returns me a bunch of gibberish in the console/log

```
      ��2˾F
2ƺx���;p}}�0���'�C�F
��b7�Ӡ�}��c��Ii���W8��I#�<dy���}4�|���{c��5�iV�@�����*�����'��
                               :ظ׻�<+�I5��^��ԓk�qi���R91R��pi7QZϢ�����V�m��� �(��8�m�c%OGN@�k��k2�>_O�����^Ya��+�����1������^�����K�3�07q���{7�ܶ0+��&sZ����w7�>f�^��A�/����d�����g�i�
                     PG?_��u�����5�i2��F$��\7(�ԟ�t8e9�3�9=Lk�@��ֽ��3��%FJ�QjI����f���qmI4֍4�^��P|�S���)Ԋ0Җ�AEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPE�����͊O6c��>y?횜����5�Z��Nuf��qr}ݶK�N�K�k̨BU'E^Ri/�W���G/�C�W?f��
                                                  RT������ׯ!�8a\�z�_^���Z�ݺEm�(��|��GJ�iS�8�k�{��ۻ��@��+"(��(�`��+��(��(��(��$��"��
                                                   2:�V��G��j���K`�S�LI���s�C�����+�����-h)[��q�
                ��/�^洫T��NMw[�^�z?]���%��ki
z�ͭ��f+��T��a����                            S��H:��dz���{2���5
                ���A#���qڇ��t�D�D2LGz�q��`��nM|�/)�B�z���K��^p__�
                                                                 ���
```

This is my service.ts

```
   postCreateProject(logo, name)
   {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    const url = EndPoints.BASE_URL + EndPoints.Projects;
    formData.append('project[logo]', logo);
    formData.append('project[name]', name)
    console.log(formData.get('project[logo]'))

    return this.httpService.postFileUpload(url, formData);
```

This is my postFileUpload in the httpService

```
postFileUpload(url: string, fmd: FormData): Observable<any> {
        console.log('post file upload')
       const headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.append('Form-Data','FileUpload');
    //    headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    //    headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(url, fmd, {headers : headers});
    }
```

If you need additional files please ask. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails 5+ and angular 4+, you might try excluding the headers and just having
`return this.http.post(url, fmd)`.
That's what I do (rails 6 with angular 10) and the data on the rails end is correct.